# What is the correct way to implement USB hardware?

Tags: usb, stm32

I'm having some problems with my USB hardware that communicates from my STM32F4 microcontroller to a computer. I have problems with certain computer setups, with some types of motherboard the USB disconnects frequently, with other types of motherboard the connection is stable. Reading in some places I realized that this could be caused by the line impedance.

Currently I use 22R resistors in the USB_DM and USB_DP lines. I decided to remove these resistors and leave the line with approximately 0R and also put a pull-up resistor in the USB_DP line. This solved my problem in some disconnected computer setups. But I would like to know the correct hardware so that I do not have disconnection problems between the microcontroller and the computer.

Below in the first image is the first hardware I used. The second image then shows the changes I made to be able to operate USB.

Edit 1: The USB connector remains the same.

[image]

Comment: Where the +5V is coming from? Is it coming from USB cable (as bus-powered device), or it is coming from local STM32F4 power supply?

Comment: This question affects both OSI level 1 on signal Transmission Line levels and quality as well as D+\D- ACK protocol on USB2 . Where are your scope signals and layout photos. Removing 27 Ohms tells me you impedance is too high and D+ pullup ought to be 1k5 to 3V or 3k to 5V roughly.

Comment: I am really wondering why the OP doesn't respond to my question posted 2 hours ago...while being seen on SE 11 mins ago...

Comment: @AliChen The + 5V comes from the microcontroller's power supply. I was checking the circuit so there was no mistake in my answer.

Comment: Then this is brutally incorrect if the "microcontroller's power supply" gets its power externally. A device should NOT source any voltage on its connector, there will be a conflict between a host and your device.

Comment: Remembering that the L7 is not connected, so the only + 5V power connected to the circuit is at L5. Can this cause conflict?

Comment: No, L5 shouldn't cause any problem, but lack of VBUS sense connection (from X11 to system sense pin) is in violation of USB specifications and might be a problem for some very old hosts.

Comment: @AliChen Reading some ST forums I found the following information:

If USB device is bus-powered, VBUS sensing is NOT mandatory: USB is connected all the time when device is powered,
If USB device is self-powered, VBUS sensing is mandatory. What do you have to say about that, is that correct? What applies to my case?

Comment: @EduardoCardoso, yes, this is correct. In bus-powered state the VBUS sense requirement is satisfied automatically. Your case is self-powered, so the VBUS_SENSE should be implemented separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to implement USB hardware is to follow ALL manufacturer's recommendations. If a hardware developer has no experience with USB implementations, the best way is to look at schematics and layout on development boards/kits.

In this particular case the implementation has several deficiencies. First it should be noted that this is a full-speed-only device, and transmission line effects (and thus the source termination) plays minor role. However, to "play nice", the manufacturer uses 22R series resistors, apparently to compensate electrical driver deficiency common to cheap FS PHY implementation IP. This schematics is from Olimex development board:
[image]
All application schematics I've seen for STM32Fxx uses 22R.

One thing is clear that 22R pull up on D+ in the second schematics is ABSOLUTELY inappropriate.

Second, if this is a device-only design, there must be two things done:

1. VBUS from Type-B connector must go to some I/O pin like "OTG_FS_VBUS" for system to be able to sense the presence of VBUS on attached cable, and
2. VBUS capacitor should be more than 1 uF but less than 10 uF.

Another detail is that ESD protection circuit should be biased from 3.3V, not +5V.

However, these are minor details that are not critical for the device operation and interface stability.

Given the vague description of "frequent disconnect" problems with "certain hosts" but not with others, I would hazard to guess that the problem is in USB interface clock going out of range. Different USB hosts may have different tolerance to USB frequency deviation, and this is the most common overlooked cause of interface instability.

To make it certain, you should run the eye diagram test on your USB port off the STM32F board. There are [documents](http://www.usb.org/developers/compliance/low_full/) on how to perform this test, depending of the equipment you have. Google for {usb eye diagram measurement}.

USB specifications call for maximum deviation from the 12Mbps data rate by +-2000 ppm. Some hosts can tolerate +-5000 ppm, some 2200ppm. It is most likely that the system crystal oscillator is not tuned properly, and the interface clock is quite off. Typical behavior is that everything might be fine on enumeration process where USB packets are short, but longer data packets will lose synch and data corruption will follow.

In general, when some interface behaves flaky, first thing is to make sure that signal amplitudes and frequencies are well within interface specification. "Random engineering" such as replacement of resistors or pushing crazy pull-ups usually is of no help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is not clear from your schematic is if you are using the 5V from the computer to power your MCU circuit. If so you may be overloading the port by drawing more current than allowed. Some computers will have a current sensor on their 5V sourcing connection which will cause a disconnection to occur if the current goes higher than allowed. Typical allowed load from a computer's host port is 500mA.

Strangely enough there are a lot of computers that do not put current limiters on the 5V feed to their type A connections. If you have a USB hub between computer and the MCU device there is a good chance that the hub has these current limit detectors on its down wind USB connectors. But again not all hubs come equipped with these, especially those that are very cheap. So beware.

Another thing that is not clear is the type of connector that you are using for the USB. A typical computer connection would be a Type-A connector and then a Type-A to SomeType-B cable would be used to connect to the target device (which in this case would be your MCU subsystem). In your changed circuit you show a USB A connector which would not be correct. Choose instead a Type-B, Mini-B or Micro-B connector. Strange thing is that your original schematic did seem to show a SomeType-B connector.

Comment: Aren't the correct limitation 100 mA until you negotiated to use more and even less if you are put into a standby mode? (I'm not a USB developer, but I have this floating around in my head...)

Comment: @Arsenal - Yes you are technically correct if you intend to build a USB compliant device. However with the way the common computer motherboards are built this becomes almost moot. Those without any current detection at the host have no way of enforcing the spec. And then there are those computers which choose to just use a PTC resettable fuse for limiting current out their host port USB connector's +5V pin. I've even seen motherboard designs that share one PTC fuse across multiple USB ports!! Motherboard manufacturers are cheap and only put current limiting in place to keep (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) circuit traces from burning up on the board in the event that a short occurs. The 500mA that I quoted is the nominal threshold for the bulk current limit detect on devices that choose to implement this feature. In practice the USB 5V switch parts also have the current detection built in will have a pretty broad range and may switch off at levels even as high as 600 or 700mA.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I made the mistake of not renaming the component in Altium, but the USB connector remained the same (USB 90GB)

Comment: @MichaelKaras I always strife to adhere to specifications, that's why I asked. I know USB power is being misused and it seems to be a sport... I have an external Lenovo optical disk drive which only works on exactly one USB port on one Lenovo desktop - they must have beefed up the 5V on that one. On all other USB ports I tried the drive couldn't spin up (was resetting then). Luckily my ASUS board seems to have some sort of usable limitation (wasn't broken afterwards...)

Comment: This is not an answer - you are *asking questions* and tossing around unlikely relevant tangents, not *providing a course of corrective action*.   The answer form is only for actual answers, to request clarification, use a *comment*.

Answer (score 0):

Neither series, nor pull-up should be necessary.

If you removed series resistors and put 0 Ohm shunts instead this might create a problem. Having nice straight traces is good for USB, despite it not being RF design.

Why do you have two pairs of capacitors? If the traces are short (which should be the case!) then 20uF is way too much.

If the traces are long you need to make sure they have matched impedance, and this goes for entire run from socket to MCU.